# Perl CPAN Can't locate CPAN/Author.pm... when trying to install nipe

Tags: perl, config, cpan

I'm trying to install "nipe" on my Windows Machine but i get this error code all the time. I have installed Strawberry Perl.

This is the error code:

```
Can't locate CPAN/Author.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CPAN::Author module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/CPAN.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/CPAN.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/App/Cpan.pm line 290.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/App/Cpan.pm line 290.
Compilation failed in require at /c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpan line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpan line 7.
```

Comment: While you may have Strawberry Perl installed, that's not the `perl` you are using. `/c/Strawberry/perl/bin/cpan` uses the first `perl` in your `PATH`, which isn't your installation of Strawberry Perl. It appears that you are using some unix emulation (Cygwin? MSYS? WSL?) and using the `perl` from that emulation. Is your goal to use SP or the unix emulation's `perl`? If the latter, please specify which unix emulation you are using. Either way, please provide information about this `nipe`.

Comment: I did not know that I was using an emulation. The perl website recommended to use strawberry perl for windows users. Here is the github nipe repo https://github.com/GouveaHeitor/nipe

Comment: Are using a Windows console. Do you see `C:\...>`?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the standard command prompt shell

Answer (score 10):

While you may have Strawberry Perl installed, that's not the `perl` you are using. `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan` uses the first `perl` in your `PATH`, which isn't your installation of Strawberry Perl. It appears that you are using some unix emulation (Cygwin? MSYS?) and using the `perl` from that emulation.

To use your Strawberry Perl build of `perl`, you could adjust your `PATH` so that SP comes before whatever `perl` you ended up using, or you could use

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan Try::Tiny Config::Simple JSON
```

or

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl -MCPAN -e"install @ARGV" Try::Tiny Config::Simple JSON
```

in lieu of

```
cpan Try::Tiny Config::Simple JSON
```

---

Similarly, if you don't adjust your path, you'll need to use

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl nipe.pl ...
```

in lieu of

```
perl nipe.pl ...
```

Comment: I executed the perl C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\cpan Try::Tiny Config::Simple JSON and it seemed to work: 
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.217)
Database was generated on Fri, 17 Jul 2020 20:10:15 GMT
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20200314)
Try::Tiny is up to date (0.30).
Config::Simple is up to date (4.58).
JSON is up to date (4.02).
(after 2nd execute) 
But what do I do know? I still can't use the perl nipe.pl install command

Comment: That is not one of the alternatives I mentioned. I have no idea which `perl` was used. /// Re "*I still can't use the perl nipe.pl install command*", If you don't specify what problem you got, I can't help. Mind you, if this is a new problem, you should post it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Forgot that you weren't informed about the context.

Comment: Are you saying the message in your question is is from `perl nipe.pl install`? If so, start by adjusting your `PATH` so that SP comes first (or at least before your other `perl`).

Answer (score 2):

If your are using windows and a bash then try to it with cmd or powershell after you applied the changes from @ikegami. Took me some time to figure out, that it had no effect to change the paths for this terminal, as it still took the paths from /usr/*/perl5/*

Comment: Same for me: On `cmd` it just worked while having no success on `git bash`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do all of the other answers, but it didn't work. Instead it appeared that it doesn't work because I tried to run it from unix shell script (sh in powershell or git bash). After moving it from .sh to .ps1 and running non-unix way it works perfectly.